# Is it possible to implement RLS in detail table only when certain user access the master table?

Tags: powerbi, dax, ssas-tabular, msbi

I have got a table visual in page 1 of Power Bi report. Page 1 visual (master table data) can be visible to all the users. When certain users visits page 1 and apply drill through only for those certain users the page 2 (detail level data) should be visible. For the rest of the users it should not be accessible.

I tried using the lookup dax filter on the detail table only when certain ids are matching.

=[MId]=LOOKUPVALUE(SiteHierarchy[MId],SiteHierarchy[MId],1)

Answer (score 2):

You can't make a page visible for one user and non visible for other. It should be two different reports or use dashboards to separate shares.